# Firebase Cloud Messaging Payload Logging

Tags: azure, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On the [Azure Notification Hub FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq/#design-amp-development) it is asserted that "Azure Notifications Hubs does not log the payload of the message in any way." Does Firebase make any similar guarantees? I can't find anything on their site.